# dataadapter.update() does not save to database

Tags: c#, dataset, dataadapter

The following code is not saving the changes from the dataset to the database via the dataadapter.update(). I display the data on a winform to text boxes.

I have a save button that should save the changes made to the database. the changes are only saved to the in memory copy of the dataset. what am i missing to get this to save the changes to the database?

```
public partial class Frm_Main : Form
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

    BindingSource binding_Login = new BindingSource();
    SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder();
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand sqlcommand = new SqlCommand();

    public Frm_Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       this.Text = "Main (" + GlobalVars.username.ToString() + ")";
       this.AcceptButton = btnSearch;
       connection.ConnectionString = GlobalVars.sqlConnString;
    }

    private void FrmMain_Close(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text))
        {
            Search();

        }
    }


    public void Search()
    {
        string sqlcommandstring = "select * from login where loginname like @search;";

        connection.Open();

        sqlcommand.CommandText = sqlcommandstring;
        sqlcommand.Connection = connection;

        sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", "%" + txtSearch.Text + "%");

        adapter.SelectCommand = sqlcommand ;
        builder.DataAdapter = adapter;

        adapter.Fill(ds,"Login") ;

        BindControls();

        txtLoginName.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", binding_Login, "LoginName"));
        txtPassword.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", binding_Login, "Password"));

        adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
        adapter.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand();
        adapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        binding_Login.MoveNext();
    }

    protected void BindControls()
    {

        binding_Login.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

    }

    private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        binding_Login.MovePrevious();
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ds.AcceptChanges();
        adapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);


    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Are you positive that your global for your `DataSet` is actually populated when you try to save?  If you don't call search, it won't have any data and would be empty.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by changing the save buttons click event to the following:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.binding_Login.EndEdit();
        adapter.Update(this.ds.Tables[0]);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in this line:

```cs
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ds.AcceptChanges();//EDIT This is the problem!
    adapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);


}
```

I had a similar problem and during debbuging I realized that if you call `.AcceptChanges()` **before** `DataAdapter.Update()`, all your modified rows will change their status to *Unchanged*. This means that `DataAdapter.Update()` will lose all the flags it needs to pick the right `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` command.

I also had problems using editing batches like:

```cs
row.BeginEdit();

// Modify several rows

row.EndEdit();
```

As I understand, the problem here happens because all changes are reserved until you call the `AcceptChanges()` method, thus causing all the row state flags to be set as *Unchanged*, making `DataAdapter.Update()` essentially blind.

In short:

- Create a `DataAdapter`.
- Set the `InsertCommand, UpdateCommand, DeleteCommand, SelectCommand`.
- Fill a `DataSet, DataTable, DataRow[]`, with the adapter.
- Make changes to your `DataSet, DataTable, DataRow[]`.
- **Make sure these changes are flagged** in the `RowState` property of the modified row(s).

  - To ensure this, don't use batch editing, and don't call `AcceptChanges()`, before the `DataAdapter.Update()` method.
- Using the same adapter, call `adapter.Update(DataSet|DataTable|DataRow[])`.